# Error using React Native using bitcoinjs-lib and ECpair / tiny-secp256k1

Tags: react-native, bitcoinjs-lib

I'm trying to use [bitcoinjs-lib](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib), but I get errors, I think it has to do with the explanation to use browserify.

For this:

```
import BIP32Factory from 'bip32';
const tinysecp = require('tiny-secp256k1')
const bip32 = BIP32Factory(tinysecp);
```

I get the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ecc.isPoint is not a function
    at Object.testEcc (testecc.js:5:1)
    at BIP32Factory (bip32.js:9:1)
```

Here's an alternative, and I get a different error:

```
import { Signer, SignerAsync, ECPairInterface, ECPairFactory, ECPairAPI, TinySecp256k1Interface } from 'ecpair';
const tinysecp: TinySecp256k1Interface = require('tiny-secp256k1');
const bip32: ECPairAPI = ECPairFactory(tinysecp);
```

Results in following error:

```
./node_modules/ecpair/src/ecpair.js 66:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (66:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   }
|   class ECPair {
>     __D;
|     __Q;
|     compressed;
```

Separately I tried to `browserify` bitcoinjs-lib and ecpair, but I think I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think bitcoin-js and tinysec are not going to work as is, because they are using some Node Js Core Features that are not Available at Runtime in an react-native app.

You can take a look at:

https://github.com/novalabio/react-native-bitcoinjs-lib as a substitute

or

https://gist.github.com/coreyphillips/4d45160fed016417a5f583f179c2cbdb a discussion about how to add bitcoin-js to react-native using [a shim file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shim)

Comment: In this example here https://github.com/bitcoinjs/tiny-secp256k1#examples (see React App) they get it to work for web. So I think it should execute fine. I think it has something to do with browserify https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib#browser they mention iOS too, so should be ok with RN. I just don't know how browserify works.